# No puedo enviar el dato desde la segunda actividad hacia el fragment

Tags: java, android

El dato lo estoy recibiendo desde mi MainActivity que es un Login, el cual envía el dato (a través de Intent) hasta la actividad Inicio (hasta aquí se envía el dato sin problemas) y desde la actividad Inicio estoy intentando enviarlo hasta mi Fragment que deriva de la misma clase Inicio (aquí es donde el dato no se envía y da error). Ayuda por favoor, muchas gracias!

Este es mi Logcat

```
   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.matias.tikon3, PID: 10514
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matias.tikon3/com.example.matias.tikon3.Inicio}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
Application terminated.
```

---

Este es mi Activity

```
  public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    TextView txtRut, etiNombre;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Esto es para iniciar en un fragment
        //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, new ImportFragment()).commit();

        txtRut= findViewById(R.id.tvRut);
        etiNombre= findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int rut = intent.getIntExtra("rut", 0);
        String nombre = intent.getStringExtra("nombre");
        String apellido = intent.getStringExtra("apellido");
        String correo = intent.getStringExtra("correo");
        String pas = intent.getStringExtra("pas");

        ImportFragment importFragment = new ImportFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("rut", rut);
        importFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contenedor, importFragment, null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        txtRut.setText(rut + "");
        etiNombre.setText(nombre);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, new ImportFragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, new GalleryFragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, new SlideshowFragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, new ToolsFragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Y este es el fragment donde quiero recibir el dato y me da error (y si tengo mi tvRut en el layout fragment_import)

```
 public class ImportFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView txtRut;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {

                int rut = getArguments().getInt("rut", 0);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_import, container, false);

            int rut = getArguments().getInt("rut", 0);

            txtRut= vista.findViewById(R.id.tvRut);

            txtRut.setText(rut);


            return vista;
        }

    }
```

Comment: agrega las actualizaciones a tu pregunta con el botón editar y **no es el mismo error ahora es otro error**: irtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: El bundle que marcas es para el Fragmento, donde realizas la transacción del Fragmento?

Comment: No, donde inicio el Fragment al que quiero enviarle datos es desde la actividad Inicio.class, lo que estoy intentando hacer ahora es enviar datos desde el Login pasando por Inicio.class y luego abrir finalmente el Fragment al que le envío los datos desde el Login.

Comment: " inicio el Fragment al que quiero enviarle datos es desde la actividad Inicio.class," ahí debes asegurar que se envía en el bundle el valor de "rut" : bundle.putInt("rut", rut); ve mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estas teniendo problemas con las referencias a las variables declaradas, lo mas recomendable es que uses la palabra clave this a la hora de trabajar con las variables instanciadas en tu objeto, por ejemplo:

```
public class MiClase {

    private String miCadena;

    public function MiClase() {
        this.miCadena = "texto de la cadena";
    }

    public getMiCadena(){
        return this.miCadena;
    }

    public setMiCadena(String newValue){
        this.miCadena = newValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error, dice que es un null object reference, lo que pasa es que quiero pasar datos desde un Login a un Fragment pero que no se conectan directamente...

Answer (score -1):

El error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.EditText.setText(int)' on a null object reference

indica que el `TextView` con id `campoRut` debe encontrarse en el archivo `fragment_consulta_usuario_url.xml`.

Cuando trata de obtener la referencia como no existe el EditText, el valor de `txtRut` es null.

```
    txtRut= (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.campoRut);
```

El error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

indica que no estas enviando el valor con key "rut" al `Fragment` :

```
  rut = getArguments().getInt("rut", 0);
```

debes asegurar que agregue los valores al Fragment y que realice la transacción.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("rut", rut);
usuarioUrlFrag.setArguments(bundle);
//*REALIZAR TRANSACCION!
```

---

El error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.matias.tikon3/com.example.matias.tikon3.Inicio}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>   0x1

Se debe a que tu aplicación trata de obtener un recurso ya que usas el método `setText()` con un valor int, debes asignar un valor tipo String para evitar este error.

```
        ...
        int rut = getArguments().getInt("rut", 0);
        ....
        txtRut.setText(rut);
        ....
```

de esta forma puedes convertir el valor a tipo String:

```
  txtRut.setText(String.valueOf(rut));
```

Comment: Si existe el EditText en el fragmentfragment_consulta_usuario_url.xml y me sigue dando error, lo que pasa es que el dato que estoy enviando lo saco de la base de datos y desde el Login (MainActivity) lo quiero pasar a un fragment que se abre dos ventanas después de haber iniciado la app.

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas asegura que envies el bundle en la transacción.

Comment: si lo hice amigo y me da error. Modificare el codigo de arriba para que veas mi nuevo codigo. Saludos!

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas ahora es otro error, agrego actualización sobre este error.

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas  Si sale otro error te sugiero realices una nueva pregunta y no varias en una (revisar [ask] ), con gusto te ayudaremos.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, ya solucione el problema de otra manera... Espero no me de problemas futuros jajaja, saludos!

Comment: De que otra forma lo resolviste?

Comment: ♦ Envié el dato a través de un SharedPreference, con este codigo lo envié (int valorrut = Integer.parseInt(txtRut.getText().toString());

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("rut", valorrut);
        editor.commit();)  y con este otro lo recibí en el fragment (SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Preferences", 0);
        int rut = prefs.getInt("rut", 0);)  Crees que me de algún problema en cuanto a memoria?

Comment: En realidad no se envia, se "guarda en la aplicación" y lo puedes obtener en cualquier parte de tu app.

Comment: Crees que pueda dar algún problema a futuro o demasiado consumo de memoria en el movil?

Comment: Para nada, si agregas los valores que tratas de enviar por el bundle se crea un archivo de preferencias (.xml) cuyo peso es muy pequeño.

Comment: Genial, gracias Jorge!